# Sailsjs download a stream of data

Tags: node.js, excel, sails.js, node-streams

I have a sails application that I'm using `exceljs` to generate an excel file. Looking at their documenatation:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#writing-xlsx

It appears they allow writing to a stream.

```
// write to a stream 
workbook.xlsx.write(stream)
    .then(function() {
        // done 
    });
```

How can I do this when the user is expecting a response?

I read the below:

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/custom-responses/adding-a-custom-response

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/custom-responses/default-responses

I also tried `res.attachment()` after saving the file and was not successful. Is there something i'm missing?

**EDIT**

The answer below is almost right. I did the following and it worked. The previous solution had sometimes corrupt files.

```
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Report.xlsx");
    return workbook.xlsx.write(res)
      .then(function() {
        res.end();
      });
```

This worked on my EC2 instance and locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs/issues/37 write the workbook to the response.

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
var sheet = workbook.addWorksheet("My Sheet");
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats');
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Report.xlsx");
workbook.xlsx.write(res);
res.end();
```

Comment: @KVISH should work now. I was confused by the use of streams. It is not necessary to use streams directly as xlsx.write can write to the response.

Comment: Weird thing is it works on my Mac but not my EC2 instance. Strange.

Comment: @KVISH whats your ec2 os? Make this another question. I could investigate the problem.